# Drag item from ListWheelScrollView in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to drag an item (Point) from a ListWheelScrollView. Unfortunately, the class provides only this method onSelectedItemChanged.
Is there a way to extend the class with other events / gestures like onLongPress or onVerticalDrag?

Thanks!

I tried to avoid the issue by creating another point on top of the selected item from the ListWheelScrollView, that would react to the onLongPress or onVerticalDrag, however, due to the dependency on the scroll, things are not always lining up on top of each other.

See the code below

```
class _Points extends StatelessWidget {
  int x;
  int selected;
  _Points(this.x, this.selected);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: x == selected ? 60 : 50,
        height: x == selected ? 60 : 50,
        child: SvgPicture.asset("svg/ball.svg"),
      ),
      RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 1,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
              width: x == selected ? 60 : 50,
              height: x == selected ? 60 : 50,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('$x',
                  textScaleFactor: x == selected ? 2 : 1,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))))
    ]);
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double itemWidth = 60.0;
  int itemCount = 20;
  int selected = 5;
  int scrollHeight = 380;
  int scrollwidth = 200;

  _Points selectedPoint = _Points(0, 0);

  FixedExtentScrollController _scrollController =
      FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 5);

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    selectedPoint = _Points(selected, selected);
    _scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: selected);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SAGWEGEWG"),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: -1,
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: scrollHeight as double,
                width: scrollwidth as double,
                child: ListWheelScrollView(
                    //  magnification: 1.0,
                    onSelectedItemChanged: (x) {
                      setState(() {
                        selected = x;
                      });
                      selectedPoint = _Points(x, x);
                      print(selectedPoint.x);
                    },
                    useMagnifier: false,
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemExtent: itemWidth,
                    children: List.generate(
                      itemCount,
                      (x) => _Points(x, selected),
                    )),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: (scrollHeight - itemWidth + 10) / 2,
                left: (scrollwidth - itemWidth + 10) / 2,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: selectedPoint,
                  onLongPress: () {
                    print("Pressed item $selected");
                  },
                ),
              )
            ]))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
`
```